# Scala: regex directly in pattern matching block

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have following regex with pattern matching:

```
val url = "/en/about"
val langRegex = "/(.{2}).*".r

val lang = url match {
  case langRegex(lang) => lang
  case _ => "en"
}
```

But I want to achieve something like this (I don't want to create extra variable for regex, but instead put it directly in matching block)

```
val url = "/en/about"
val lang = url match {
  case "/(.{2}).*".r(lang) => lang
  case _ => "en"
}
```

I'm getting compiler error in second case?  I just substituted **langRegex(lang)** with **"/(.{2}).*".r**, these expression should be equal, shouldn't it?

Why this is an error?

Comment: The thing is that you just can't do that, you need a precompiled pattern. What you can do is either use an `if` inside and use some string manipulation if the string matches your regex, or just use a simpler code like in http://ideone.com/CJMS1A

Comment: Or use [`case s if url.matches("/(.{2}).*") => s.replaceFirst("/(.{2}).*","$1")`](http://ideone.com/dqlW4z).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work because you can only match *values* as defined in http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html. 
In the first example, your match is of the form `StableId ‘(’ [Patterns] ‘)’` where `StableId` is a `value` or an `object` but not a `def` that could change anytime it's executed.

Your second example is not working because `"/(.{2}).*".r` is not a StableId. Your second example is not working because the following example is also not working:

```
val url = "/en/about"
def langRegex = "/(.{2}).*".r

val lang = url match {
  case langRegex(lang) => lang
  case _ => "en"
}
```

where I changed your `langRegex` definition to a `def` and it's thus not a StableId anymore.

Comment: @moreo you can also check this as accepted answer if it answers your question